# Remove passcode from login page

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, web-ide

I'm developing an hybrid app and I want to skip the passcode screen after having logged.

I've tried following a post about Kapsel-Logon where it is explained how to implement it, but it doesn't work for me. I don't know if the latest release makes changes null.

The file I tried to modify is:

```
C:\KapselSDK\plugins\logon\www\common\modules\LogonController.js
```

Can you help me or suggest where I wrong or what can I do/look?

Answer (score -1):

yes the file that you need to change is the LogonController.js 
You can find [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/07/17/getting-started-with-kapsel-sap-fiori-client-sp09/#passcode) what exactly you need to do in order to get rid the passcode screen.

Good luck!

Comment: you should give more detailed solution than just a link